# Disabled button when textInputField is invalid on change text Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new on Flutter.
I'm trying to disabled button while I compile textFormField and it is invalid.
My problem is that it works only if I click on "confirm" on keyboard and not *while* I compile my input.
So would like disable button while I write the input.

I've done a pastebin for example:

https://pastebin.com/q5WuwrCm

```
class AddCartButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return AddCartButtonState();
  }
}
class AddCartButtonState extends State<AddCartButton>{
  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();
  bool isValid = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _addToCart(){
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("QUANTITY"),
            content: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                    controller: myController,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: "quantity"),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[],
                    autovalidate: true,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        isValid  = false;
                        return "the quantity cannot be empty";
                      } else if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                        isValid = false;
                        return "the quantity must be valid number";
                      } else {
                        isValid = true;
                        return null;
                      }
                    }
                )
              ],
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  disabledTextColor: Colors.grey,
                  child: Text("add"),
                  onPressed: isValid ? () { print("is valid"); }: null
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do this with the onChange method of the TextFormField, but it's a bit confusing what you want to achieve. You want the button to be disabled while you type, and then after a second of not typing you want the button to be enabled again?

Comment: No, I want only disable button while I'm typing on input, but only if the input is invalid. Instead if the input become valid the button should be enabled. OnChange in theory is useless because textInput has validator that catch when input change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addListener()` function on your `TextEditingController myController`.

```dart
myController.addListener((){
    //With this, you can "listen" all the changes on your text while
    //you are typing on input
    print("value: ${myController.text}");
    //use setState to rebuild the widget
    setState(() {
        //you can check here if your text is valid or no
        //_isValidText() is just an invented function that returns
        //a boolean representing if the text is valid or not
        if(_isValidText(myController.text)) isValid = true;
        else isValid = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you but doesn't work, same problem. The button is disabled not while I'm typing but when I "confirm" on keyboard

Comment: Did your app print the `value: ${myController.text}` from the listener function? And, can you remove the `autovalidate` property to false?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to achieve the following code works for you. The conditions I set are the same as your validation rules:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  Function _submitFunction;
  // We need a reusable timer and it needs to not be null so that we can cancel it from th start.
  Timer _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () => print('initialTimer'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Auto disable button'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: _textEditingController,
                onChanged: (text) {
                  setState(() {
                    _submitFunction = null;
                  });
                  restartTimer();
                },
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit'),
                onPressed: _submitFunction,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  void submitForm(){
    print(_textEditingController.text);
  }

  void enableButton(){
    if(_textEditingController.text != ''){
      setState(() {
        _submitFunction = submitForm;
      });
    }
  }

  void restartTimer(){
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1500), enableButton);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method .

```
  bool isEnable = false;
void validateButton() {
    bool isValid = true;

    isValid = userEmail.isNotEmpty &&
        userPassword.isNotEmpty &&
        validateEmail(userEmail) &&
        userPassword.length >= 8;

    setState(() {
      isEnable = isValid;
    });
  }
```

now in your Textfield onChanged method you have to call this function

like This

```
onChanged: (email) {
                        userEmail = email;
                        setState(() {});
                        validateButton();
                      },
```

and in your Login Button

```
isEnable?ActiveButton():DisableButton()
```