# Flutter equivalent of string validation on key up

Tags: forms, validation, flutter, textfield

The scenario is as follows:

I have a `TextFormField` and a `FlatButton`. I want to enable the `FlatButton` only when the `TextFormField` is valid, and I would like to check the validation after each character is typed.

I am using a `Form` with a `GlobalKey`. I have tried using `onChanged` and the value that is passed to the callback function is correct, but for some reason the validation that occurs when I run `$_globalKey.currentState.validate()` is always one character behind. So to make it really simple, I only validated if the string was empty. When it was actually empty (after deleting the last character) `validate()` returned `true` but after typing one character it returned `false`.

Using `autovalidate` and that worked for the validation part alone but I don't know how to attach the enabling of a button to that. Does anyone know how to get validation to work "correctly" in this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: You can with addListener. Please check this link,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59652569/12716244

Comment: Thanks for the link @FarukAYDIN. Just to confirm, there's no way to tie that to the `validator` property of the field itself? Just have to write a separate function? I know I could use a separate function and call in two places, but other than that no way?

Answer (score 0):

create a key for form

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

after add to addlistener this code.

```
if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) 
{
    return;
}
```

this is your listener

```
myController.addListener((){
    setState(() {
        if(_isValidText(myController.text) && _formKey.currentState.validate()) 
            isValid = true;

        else 
            isValid = false;
    });
});
```